# Get selected option from a list

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

How to get the selected option in this list, in apex class :

```
<apex:column headerValue="Type d'ctivité">
     <apex:selectList value="{!typeAct}" size="1" >
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!nomAct}"/>
     </apex:selectList> 
</apex:column>
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

The selected value will be stored in your `typeAct` variable, since your picklist is bound to it via the `value` attribute.